# Untity Game Destroy all objects instead of one

Tags: unity, c#

I have two game objects with the same script.

[image]

In the PicUpSys script I have this code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PicUpSys : MonoBehaviour
{

    public InvSys _InvSys;

    public bool SmallStone;
    public bool SmallTree;

    public GameObject ME;

    void Start()
    {
        ME = gameObject;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if (SmallStone == true)
            {
                if (_InvSys.SelectedSlot == "1")
                {
                    if (_InvSys.FirstSlotCont == "")
                    {
                        _InvSys.FirstSlotCont = "SmallStone (1)";
                        _InvSys.FirstSlotContN = 1;
                        _InvSys.Stone = _InvSys.Stone + 1;
                        Destroy(ME, 1);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        _InvSys.FirstSlotCont = "SmallStone (" + _InvSys.FirstSlotContN + ")";
                        _InvSys.FirstSlotContN = 1;
                        _InvSys.Stone = _InvSys.Stone + 1;
                        Destroy(ME, 1);
                    }
                }

                else if (_InvSys.SelectedSlot == "2")
                {

                }

                else if (_InvSys.SelectedSlot == "3")
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I start the game ME is automatically set to the current game object.

[image]

But when I click the SmallStone the script destroy SmallStone and SmallStone(1)

How I can do to only destroy SmallStone?

Comment: Why do you have a public GO that you'll set manually? Why not Destroy([this.]gameObject, 1) instead? It might sort out the issue as well. Otherwise you should also do something somewhere else causing this issue

Comment: GetMouseButtonDown checks *whether* the mouse button is clicked. It does not check *which object* has been clicked. Consider implementing [OnMouseDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html) if you want your object to react only when *its attached collider* is clicked.

Comment: @DMGregory its ok how it is i just want it to destroy the clicked object and not all

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try defining an object, in the code, as a variable. Then, go into the inspector, and set that game object to each stone as it's self. Finally, make the code destroy that game object variable.

Comment: Still not working i created the `public Object Me;` but still destroying everything

Comment: Did you remove the line of code that sets varble "me" to the gameobejct?

Comment: Yes i removed and created `public Object Me;`

Comment: This is wrong, see DMGregory's comment on the question for the correct answer.